# Delete multiples items C# EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreach, sql-delete

I'm using Entity Framework.

```
try
{
    List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = (from row in dtg.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                          where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Borrar"].Value) == true
                                          select row).ToList();
    if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("¿Deseas borrar {0} registros?", selectedRows.Count), "Confirmacion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows)
        {
            using (var context = new SistemaVentasEntities())
            {
                REGISTROS registro= context.AUX_REGISTROS .Where(m => m.ID== m.ID).FirstOrDefault();
                context.REGISTROS.Remove(registro);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            this.CargarGrid();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Here, everything is correct, eliminates the number of records that I select. but only continuous, I'd like delete just items selected, if I have a list of ID `{ 1,2,3,4 }` and I want to delete the 1 and 3, it doesn't work, that code deletes the 1 and 2 for example.

I'm using a checkbox into the DataGridView, clicking on a button.

Comment: Ugh... this is why I'm using `PetaPoco` these days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing. Before actually deleting the entities try first to find then and put them into separate collection, then in *separate* loop remove them from DB and then call the save changes on context. My bet is that you are kind-of modifying the collection on which you are looping. That's causing you the problem with selective deletion.

Comment: This is what im trying to do...but i cant get identify the items i wanna delete

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue resides in this bit:

```
.Where(m => m.ID== m.ID)
```

You are comparing the id in the filter with the id in the filter (which will always be true).  I think you want something like:

```
.Where(m => m.ID == row.ID)
```

... except the code to retrieve your ID from your row is probably exactly that.  :)

Answer (score 0):

[EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) has a really nice extension method for this kind of  jobs. You can find more details [here](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended#batch-update-and-delete).

Example from documentation page:

```
//delete all users where FirstName matches
context.Users
    .Where(u => u.FirstName == "firstname")
    .Delete();
```